# Java: Understanding execution of static methods

Tags: java, performance

There are two methods `printA` inside `class A` and `printB` inside `class B`. `printA` is a `static` method and `printB` is a non-static method. Both the methods are `synchronized`. There exact 100 million threads fired on both `printA` and `printB` each.

Which method execution will take less time?

My understanding of `static`methods revolves around object creation related stuff. You know, If the class obj is not needed to call static method. Or util methods can be static methods. Or static methods are global and hard to unit test.
In this case I guess that execution of static method will be faster because it will be created once and then reused by every other thread.

Comment: "Which method execution will take less time?"

Comment: "exact 100 million threads". Wow, how are those generated?

Comment: A concurrent system is *nondeterministic*, so it couldn't be said with certainty. It is not even clear what "will take less time" should mean in such a setting.

Comment: You should try this sort of thing. It would only take a few lines of code.

Comment: Methods are always created once and used by all threads. Unless you have only one object printB will be faster as you are not locking on a shared resource.

Comment: If you really do have hundreds of millions of threads, it is not a job for a single JVM running on one system. To give each thread of 100 million 0.1% of a processor would take a hundred thousand processors. Even allowing for multiple cores in each processor chip, that means very high memory latency, because of physical distance and switching latency, for at least some processors accessing common cache lines in the JVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may find printB faster if you have a lot of objects and multiple processor cores. printA is synchronized on the class object, so all calls to it are done one-at-a-time. printB is synchronized on its object, and so multiple printB calls can run in parallel.

You really need to benchmark your methods, in the context of your program, on a hardware configuration typical of where the program will run.

Comment: Good point! But where do you know on what the methods are synchronized?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks. Typo corrected.

Comment: @Ingo From the Java Language Specification. The question says that the methods are synchronized, not that each contains a synchronized block.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan All right, that makes sense.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Can you please explain on the `printA being synchronized at class level` and `printB at its object`?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Suppose you have declared `class X`, and `X x = new X();`, with `static synchronized void printA(){...}` and `synchronized void printB(){...}`. An `X.printA()` call is synchronized on the Class object for class A. An `x.printB()` call is synchronized on the object referenced by x.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough in theory static method should be faster as non-static methods are [late bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding), in practice there's usually no performance difference between static and non static members

EDIT: @Patricia Shanahan makes a good point though

Answer (score 0):

If `printB` is called on different objects of `Class B`, will be able to run in parallel as `printB` holds lock on its *object* or `this`.

While `printA` will hold lock on `.class` object so if multiple threads call `printB` will be serialized even if calling on different objects.

So conclusion, `printB` may seem faster.

*NOTE: Also the actual output depends on how many synchronized methods you have in your classes.*

So I would say that it is very difficult to comment on that and actual benchmarking may provide exact results.